# How do I handle multiple requests to python program using zeromq and threading or async?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zeromq, python-multithreading, zerorpc

I have a little program, which does some calculations in background, when I call it through **`zerorpc`** module in python 2.7.

Here is my code:

```
is_busy = False

class Server(object):
   def calculateSomeStuff(self):
       global is_busy

        if (is_busy):
            return 'I am busy!'

        is_busy = True

        # calculate some stuff

        is_busy = False
        print 'Done!'
        return 

    def getIsBusy(self):
        return is_busy

s = zerorpc.Server(Server())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:66666")
s.run()
```

**What should I change** to make this program returning **`is_busy`** when I call `.getIsBusy()` method, after `.calculateSomeStuff()` has started doing it's job?

As I know, there is no way to make it asynchronous in python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need multi-threading for real concurrency and exploit more than one CPU core if this is what you are after. See the Python threading module, **`GIL`**-lock details & possible workarounds and literature.

If you want a cooperative  solution, read on.

**`zerorpc`** uses **`gevent`** for asynchronous input/output. With `gevent` you write coroutines (also called greenlet or userland threads) which are all running cooperatively on a single thread. The thread in which the `gevent` input output loop is running. The `gevent` **`ioloop`** takes care of resuming coroutines waiting for some I/O event.

The key here is the word **cooperative**. Compare that to threads running on a single CPU/core machine. Effectively there is nothing concurrent,
but the operating system will preempt <sub>( *verb*:
take action in order to prevent (an anticipated event) from happening )</sub> a running thread to execute the next on and so on so that every threads gets a fair chance of moving forward.

This happens fast enough so that it feels like all threads are running at the same time.

If you write your code cooperatively with the `gevent` input/output loop, you can achieve the same effect by being careful of calling **`gevent.sleep(0)`** often enough to give a chance for the `gevent` `ioloop` to run other coroutines.

It's literally cooperative multithrading. I've heard it was like that in Windows 2 or something.

So, in your example, in the heavy computation part, you likely have some loop going on. Make sure to call `gevent.sleep(0)` a couple times per second and you will have the illusion of multi-threading.

I hope my answer wasn't too confusing.